# dot product of $\vec{AD}$ and $\vec{BC}$

Tags: vectors

if  $A,B,C,D$ be $4$ points in a space satisfying $|\vec{AB}| = 3\;,|\vec{BC}| = 7\;|\vec{CD}| = 11\;|\vec{DA}| = 9$.

find  $\vec{AD}\cdot \vec{BC}=$

using $|\vec{DA}|^2+|\vec{BC}|^2=|\vec{AB}|^2+|\vec{CD}|^2$

i could not go further, could some help me with this, thanks

Comment: There is not enough data. These points can be arranged to create a triangle ACD with sides 10, 11 and 9 and or quadrilateral in many ways. The angle between $AD$ and $BC$ varies, so it is impossible to calculate dot product with only distances given.

Comment: By the way, $\vec{AC}\cdot \vec{BD}$ is equal to $0$.